# How to search russian texts in Lucene index?

Tags: java, lucene

I can not understand where I was wrong. 
My code, where "/ home/test/03m8894---20070213134234.txt" - file with the English text, and "/ home/test/01---20061121103506.txt" - file with the Russian text. 
Both files are encoded in UTF-8. 
The result of the execution of the program: 
1 
0 
Ie the program finds only text in English and Russian text ignored. 
Although if you do

```
            for (int m = 0; m <totalDocs; m + +) { 

            Document thisDoc = reader.document (m); 
            System.out.print (thisDoc.get ("partnum"));
```

the text field partnum correctly, no errors in the output encoding on the screen.

```
 RAMDirectory directory = new RAMDirectory();

        IndexWriter writer =
                //new IndexWriter(directory, new SimpleAnalyzer(), true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
                new IndexWriter(directory, new RussianAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30), true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
        File f1[] = {new File("/home/test/03m8894---20070213134234.txt"), new File("/home/test/01---20061121103506.txt")};

        String strLine1 = "";
        for (int x = 0; x < f1.length; x++) {
            Document doc = new Document();
            int length = (int) f1[x].length();
            if (length != 0) {
                char[] cbuf = new char[length];
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f1[x]));
                final int read = isr.read(cbuf);
                strLine1 = new String(cbuf, 0, read);
                isr.close();
                doc.add(new Field("partnum", strLine1, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
                //doc.add(new Field("description", "Illidium Space Modulator", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
                writer.addDocument(doc);
            }

        }
writer.close();

        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory);
        IndexReader reader = searcher.getIndexReader();
        int totalDocs = reader.numDocs();



        for (int m = 0; m < totalDocs; m++) {

            Document thisDoc = reader.document(m);

     String tmp_str=thisDoc.get("partnum");

     Query query = new TermQuery(new Term("partnum", tmp_str));

     TopDocs rs = searcher.search(query, null, 10);
            System.out.println(rs.totalHits);
```

Comment: Could you publish those text files for us to download, so we can try this ourselves?

Answer (score 1):

You said the files are UTF-8 encoded, but you use:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f1[x]));
```

This relies on the default encoding, which is likely not UTF-8. try:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f1[x]), "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's is not critical, because all files in UTF-8 and default system and file encoding is UTF-8...